# Mantel Test in R

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I am trying to run a **Mantel** test in **R** on two distances (*Geographic Distances and Genetic Distancse*).

The data is saved in an **Excel** file as 2 columns; each row has the geographic distance and genetic distance between 2 populations.

I am running the following command which returns to be wrong for some reason

```
mantel.rtest(mydata$Dis, mydata$Fst, nrepet = 99)
```

the error message is as follow:

```
Error in mantel.rtest(mydata$Time, mydata$Fst, nrepet = 99) : 
  Object of class 'dist' expected
```

would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: in what package might one find `mantel.rtest()`?

Comment: Can you make a connection between the error message and the example at the bottom of the documentation at `?mantel.rtest`? Notice what you were instructed to do to each input to `mantel.rtest`?

Comment: mantel.rtest is in the package ade4. You should try to conform your input to the class "dist". You can probably convert your objects to class "dist" using some additional function in ade4. But why don't you use mantel.test in ape?

Answer (score 2):

You have to transform your data into dist() data. dis.dist<-dist(mydata$Dis) and fst.dist<-dist(mydata$Fst) and then run the mantel.rtest with the dist values.